# how to convert image to base64 without image loss in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, base64, image-conversion

Following method i ill try, but the image not show in properly and it getting loss

```swift
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    img_View.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    strImage = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    print(strImage)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

here lossy image [Corrupted image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhew8.png)
While i decode image into my computer i'm getting full image with slightly blur, But while i'm send my base64 string to service(WEBAPI)(Windows PC), they get only half of the image. can somebody help me how to fix this issue

Comment: what do you mean "not show properly"? do you mean the `strImage` is not printing out the encoded image?

Comment: @Fonix, He i getting patial image like half image get corrupted.

Comment: maybe the option `Encoding64CharacterLineLength` is interfering with whatever is using that base64 data, try not using any option

Comment: @fonix, thanks, it works for me, but in API team getting half image.

Answer (score 1):

## swift 4

this question is bit old but as its one of the top search result in google i will add the solution for swift4.

> You need to define the option of encoding

```
let image = UIImage(named: "yourimagename")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let base64Str = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably capping it with the option `CharacterLineLength`

I just do this: `imageData.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
    var sample = UIImage(named: "try-swift-logo")
    let imageData:Data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(sample!)!
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```